# How to generate an editable document using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm new to Ruby on rails. I work on Rails 5. I have a requirement of generating PDF document on click of a button with the details in the database, which I achieved using PRAWN gem. Now there is a requirement that On click of a button I should get an option, in which I should be able to select whether to generate a document in PDF or editable format(DOCX or any other format).

Can we achieve this with PRWAN gem in rails 5?

Please suggest me if there are any other options available.

Answer (score 0):

The gem [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) works only the pdf.

I belive that all you need is the gem [htmltoword](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword)

Usage:

```
require 'htmltoword'

# Configure the location of your custom templates
Htmltoword.config.custom_templates_path = 'some_path'

my_html = '<html><head></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html>'
document = Htmltoword::Document.create(my_html, word_template_file_name)
file = Htmltoword::Document.create_and_save(my_html, file_path, word_template_file_name)
```